# Magento cart error "Maximum one item to add the shopping cart."

Tags: magento-1.6, magento

I checked the option in the `system -> config -> Inventory` and it's set to 1000 the `Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart` i can add the same product so it supplements the Qty of that product by one more, but if i add another product i get this **Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart** , any idea how can i fix the cart so i will be able to add more items to the cart ?

PS: i have **Magento ver. 1.6.1.0**

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Can you post the exact error text you're getting when you attempt to add the item to the cart?  With that we'll be able to find where Magento throws the exception that's causing your error, and then check the PHP logic around that error to see why it's rejecting your item.

Comment: @AlanStorm thanks, the error is “Maximum one item to add the shopping cart.” , which file exactly you want me to check ?

Comment: That exact error message/wording doesn't appear anywhere in the default 1.6 CE code. That says to me that someone has either changed your error messaging, or there's a third party extension throwing that error.  You'll need to find which file it appears in (search for "item to add the shopping cart") and that should help you track it down.

Comment: didn't find the problem, i checked every where.. can you give me more hints please ?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend you to do the following:

1. First check system -> config -> Inventory settings for all your stores. Typically users get such errors when the settings are inappropriate on different store leves.
2. But if you get this error adding another product, then go to the Inventory tab of your product and check whether the Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart is populated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your error 'Maximum one item to add the shopping cart.' is quite unique and it's actually a custom error not native to Magento. I've found it in some code of a client of mine. You'll have to look for the following code blocks in a few files:

```
      if ($cartItems >= 1) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Maximum one item to add the shopping cart.'));
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
       }
```

and

```
    if ($params['product'] != $productId) {
        if ($cartItems >= 1) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Maximum one item to add the shopping cart.'));
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
       }
    }
```

and

```
    if ($params['product'] != $productId) {
        if ($cartItems > 1) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->__('Maximum one product to add the shopping cart.'));
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }
    }
```

and

```
       if ($item->getProductId() != $productId) {
           if ($cartItems >= 1) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Maximum one item to add the shopping cart.'));
                $this->_goBack();
                return;
            }
        }
```

You'll be likely to find them in `/app/code/local/{Name}/{Module}/controllers/Checkout/CartController.php` `/app/code/local/{Name}/{Module}/controllers/Checkout/OnepageController.php` `/app/code/local/{Name}/{Module}/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php` 
Mentionably, {Name} is not necessarily limited to one extension... I've found it in multiple, perform a search all through all the files in /app/code/local to be sure. 
In order to 'fix' it, either change the '1' in `if ($cartItems > 1) {` to some other (higher) number, or comment that if statement out and replace it with `if(false) {`.

Answer (score -1):

```
 if ($params['product'] != $productId) {
        if ($cartItems > 1) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->__('Maximum one product to add the shopping cart.'));
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }
    }
```